# Tomcat 7 startup.bat exception

Tags: tomcat7

When i run startup.bat file of Tomcat 7 i m getting the following error.

> INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
>   Mar 01, 2014 12:18:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>   SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
>   java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:430)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:640)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:664)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
>   Mar 01, 2014 12:18:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
>   SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:664)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
>       ... 12 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:430)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:640)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
>       ... 13 more

When I run the url `http://localhost:8080`, I get the prompt for authentication. If i give default username and password as 'tomcat', it prompts me again without successful login.
Here is my **tomcat-users.xml** file

```
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager-gui"/>
```

**Can anybody help me please?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may have another instance of Tomcat already running in the background and using port 8080. Try shutting it down with `shutdown.bat`, or look for a java process in the Windows Task Manager. You can also reboot if you really want to be sure that there's no other instance running.

Comment: Thank you David for the response. I tried shutting down tomcat services. But it did not solve. I changed HTTP port number 8080 to different value. It started working

Answer (score 8):

the port 8080 might be used by other application. go to server.xml in tomcat and change the port number,
and restart the tomcat. To change port follow
http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/

Comment: "by **other application**" (i.e. not necessarily another Tomcat instance) -- that was it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I ran 
netstat -ano > output.txt
In output.txt file, I saw the the System process with PID 4 was holding onto that 8080 port. I could not release it in any way so I restarted the system. After that it was fine.

Comment: To find the application name as well: try adding the -b flag (netstat -abno). OR After you find the PID, for windows open Task Manager and check for the application name against that PID (in case PID column is not visible) right click on the table Header and select the column to make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

An error like `Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]` means that Tomcat cannot start bind to (use) port 8080.

I had a silar `Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-80"]` on port 80 the other day.

Try to connect with telnet on 8080 (or whatever port this error occurs on) to figure out what process is using this port.

1. Open a telnet connection `telnet localhost 8080` (or whatever host and port you are using)
2. Expect to see a blank screen with blinking cursor. If you get a `Could not open connection to the host` or similar error nothing is using this port after all.
3. Type a command like `GET` (assuming HTTP protocol)
4. See if the server responds whith a HTTP responds which could reveil  a bit about what process is serving this port.

Answer (score 0):

You may have another instance of Tomcat already running in the background and using port 8080. Go to Task Manager and end all the java*.exe processes.