# Error while applying SSL certificate in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I bought SSL certificate from https://www.gogetssl.com/ggssl/.

My tomcat version -

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/ec2-user/apache-tomcat-8.0.36
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/ec2-user/apache-tomcat-8.0.36
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/ec2-user/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/ec2-user/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/ec2-user/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
Server built:   Jun 9 2016 13:55:50 UTC
Server number:  8.0.36.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     4.4.5-15.26.amzn1.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_99-mockbuild_2016_03_28_23_53-b00
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Once I received SSL certificate, I have added it in my keystore --

```
keytool7 -list -keystore /home/ec2-user/myweb.jks 
Enter keystore password:  

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

server, Oct 18, 2016, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 3D:3A:2A:59:C7:4C:78:1B:38:0F:3E:FF:77:86:44:D5:59:6A:5B:FD
```

I have made changes in server.xml as following :

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="server" 
    keystoreFile="/home/ec2-user/myweb.jks" keystorePass="XXXXXX" />
```

After restarting my tomcat instance, server throws below error :

```
18-Oct-2016 08:37:24.858 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
 java.io.IOException: Alias name server does not identify a key entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:608)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getKeyManagers(JSSESocketFactory.java:546)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:371)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:748)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:459)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:869)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:580)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:603)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)

18-Oct-2016 08:37:24.859 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:869)
```

Please help me resolving this?

Thanks
Pari

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111338/tomcat-7-startup-bat-exception

Comment: try to remove `keyAlias="server" ` to see if it helps

Comment: I have removed keyAlias tag.. tomcat didn't throw any error. But I can't access my website through 8443 Port but website is accessible through 8080.

Comment: I don't think my problem is related/duplicated with mentioned post Anand

Comment: You need to import the private key into your keystore and provide that alias in the server.xml and not the truststore cert alias.